Convergence in Expectation for Ergodic Markov Chains
Let $X_n \in \mathbb{N}^m$ be a discrete-time Markov chain process that is $m$-dimensional with all entries being non-negative integers. Suppose that the Markov chain is irreducible, positive recurrent, and aperiodic. Therefore, the $n$-step transition probability converges to the stationary distribution. Let $X$ denote the (random) state under stationary distribution.
Question: Under what conditions of function $f$ do we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]?$$
For example, $X_n$ converges to $X$ in total variation distance. Therefore, the above holds when function $f$ is bounded.
However, do we have  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{n}^i] = \mathbb{E}[X^i]$, where $X_n^i$ and $X^i$ denote the $i$-th index of $X_n$ and $X$, respectively?

Define $F(x^{1},x^{2},...,x^{m})=f(x^{i})$. $F$ is bounded and continuous if $f$ is.

@geetha290krm Very sorry—a typo in my question. I have fixed it.

Gambler's ruin is a counter-example (absorbing at 0, so the only stationary distribution is $\delta_0$).

@D.Thomine I see. Thank you!!

@D.Thomine: A (non-trivial) chain with an absorbing state can't be positive recurrent.

@ John Dawkins: That depends on your definitions. My mistake is rather than such a chain cannot be irreducible (and in this case definitions may diverge from one reference to another).

But yes, this may actually be true as soon as $f$ is integrable under the invariant measure, which is needed anyway to make sense of $\mathbb{E} (f (X))$, and we start from a fixed point. I'm not entirely sure. It's probably false if we allow any starting distribution, as then it's easy to make $\mathbb{E} (f(X_n))$ infinite.

Contrary to what I wrote in my comment, the answer is yes under very mild conditions.
Setting : $(X_n)$ is an irreducible, aperiodic, strongly recurrent Markov chain on a countable state space $\Omega$ (in your case, $\Omega = \mathbb{N}^m$). Its unique stationary probability measure is $\mu$. We fix $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ which is integrable for $\mu$.
Theorem : Let $\nu \in \mathcal{P} (\Omega)$ such that $\frac{d \nu}{d \mu}$ is bounded. Assume that $X_0$ is chosen under $\nu$ and $X$ under $\mu$. Then $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \mathbb{E} (f(X_n)) = \mathbb{E} (f(X))$.
Proof : Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is integrable, there exists $A \subset \Omega$ finite such that $\int_{A^c} |f| \ d \mu \leq \varepsilon$.
Let $\nu_n$ be the distribution of $X_n$ (i.e. $\nu_n = \nu P^n$ with $P$ the Markov kernel). Let $C$ be a upper bound on $\frac{d \nu}{d \mu}$. Then $\frac{d \nu_n}{d \mu} \leq C$ for all $n$. In addition,
$$\mathbb{E} (f(X_n)) = \int_\Omega f \ d \nu_n 
= \int_\Omega f \ d \mu + \int_A f \ d (\nu_n-\mu) + \int_{A^c} f \ d (\nu_n - \mu).$$
Since $\nu_n$ converges to $\mu$ in total variation and $A$ is finite, for all large enough $n$,
$$\left| \int_A f \ d (\nu_n-\mu) \right| \leq \varepsilon.$$
In addition,
$$\left| \int_{A^c} f \ d (\nu_n-\mu) \right| \leq \int_{A^c} |f| \ d (C \mu + \mu) \leq (C+1) \varepsilon.$$
Hence, for all large enough $n$,
$$\left| \mathbb{E} (f(X_n)) - \mathbb{E} (f(X)) \right| \leq (C+2) \varepsilon,$$
and thus $\mathbb{E} (f(X_n))$ converges to $\mathbb{E} (f(X))$.
Remark : This applies in particular if $X_0 = x$ is deterministic, since then $\frac{d \nu}{d \mu} = \mu(x)^{-1} \mathbf{1}_{\{x\}}$ is bounded by $\mu(x)^{-1}$.
Remark : Without this assumption on the distribution of $X_0$, it is easy to get counter-examples. For instance, consider the random walk on $\mathbb{N}$ with transition probabilities $p_{n \to n+1} = 1/3$ and $p_{n \to n-1} = 2/3$. It has a stationary distribution $\pi$ such that $\pi (n) = C 2^{-n}$ for some $C$. Take $f(n) = 1.5^n$; then it is integrable for $\pi$. But if you choose an initial distribution which decays in $C 1.1^{-n}$, then $f(X_0)$ has infinite expectation, and since this random walk moves by $1$ step at each time, $f(X_n)$ has infinite expectation for all $n$.
